# Rails asset pipeline javascript issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm a bit lost. I'm able to include `icheck-rails`gem into my Rails app if I include the js [snippet](https://github.com/cubus/icheck-rails) in my `application.js` file:

```
function icheck() {
  if($(".icheck-me").length > 0){
    $(".icheck-me").each(function(){
      var $el  = $(this);
      var skin = ($el.attr('data-skin')  !== undefined) ? "_" + $el.attr('data-skin') : "",
      color    = ($el.attr('data-color') !== undefined) ? "-" + $el.attr('data-color') : "";
      var opt  = {
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox' + skin + color,
        radioClass: 'iradio' + skin + color,
      }
      $el.iCheck(opt);
    });
  }
}

$(function(){
    icheck();
})
```

However, when I try to add a separate `app/assets/javascript/icheck.js` file with the same code snippet, I no longer see the icheck buttons on the forms, and I see this error in the browser console:

[image: Browswer error]

And when I drill down, it has something to do with the binding:

[image: Imgur]

Any idea why I can't include the javascript in a separate file called `icheck.js`, as opposed to keeping it in the `application.js` manifest file.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add `icheck.js` to [the manifest file](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives)?

Comment: believe so, i have `//= require_tree .` in the `application.js` file, and the `icheck.js` file is located at `app/assets/javascripts/`.

Comment: Does your `//= require_tree .` occur before or after the line where you have `//= require 'icheck'` in your manifest file?

Comment: In order for you to use icheck-rails you should have this line `//= require 'icheck'` in application.js (I'm talking about the file that comes with the gem itself not the one you just created). Rename the file that contains the code from your question to something else different than icheck and it should work.

Comment: thanks both for pushing me in the right direction. it looks like it was a namespace issue after all.  i renamed the file to something else, and it works now.